# Stock android camera app. How to prevent default settings from taking over

Tags: settings, camera, stock-android, default-applications, camera-flash

I'm on Android 5 KitKat but I've seen this in Android 4.x  as well. The stock camera app has the settings for contrast sharpness brightness etc.

I always want the sharpness to be maximum along with the contrast, that is, high values for both these parameters. I change them and later on they will reset to defaults. I tried to use other apps like open camera but they are not native apps and their control of the camera is not that good.

My question is how do I permanently keep these high contrast and high sharpness settings without the defaults taking over periodically. And  corollary to that , I wonder what event causes the settings to be reset to default... is it a certain time period? Or after coming from sleep. I wanted to know if there's some sort of a settings file which I can edit to permanently keep these modified settings. I'm attaching a picture of what the look like. Please don't recommend an alternate app. I would like to know what I can do with this app.

[image: stock camera Android app & its settings]

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Jiayu s3 rooted. Running Android 4.4.4. Then that would not be KitKat.... my mistake.

Comment: But the same problem is there through the Android series from 2.x -5.x. I don't know  bout lollipop